# TypeError: MIL.forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'edge_index'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

The code i'm trying to run is:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

# Define your custom dataset
class UCFCrimeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, features, labels):
        self.features = features
        self.labels = labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.features[index]
        y = self.labels[index]
        return x, y

class GCNFeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(GCNFeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        # Define your GCN layers
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        # Implement the forward pass of the GCN feature extractor
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return x


class EDLHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_classes):
        super(EDLHead, self).__init__()
        # Define your EDL head
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Implement the forward pass of the EDL head
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


class MIL(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_extractor, head, loss_fn):
        super(MIL, self).__init__()
        self.feature_extractor = feature_extractor
        self.head = head
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn

    def forward(self, data, edge_index):
        # Extract features from the data
        features = self.feature_extractor(data.x, data.edge_index)

        # Classify the data
        predictions = self.head(features)

        # Compute the loss
        loss = self.loss_fn(predictions, data.y)

        return loss


def train(model, train_loader, val_loader, epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Train the model on the training data
        model.train()
        for data in train_loader:
            loss = model(data)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        # Evaluate the model on the validation data
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for data in val_loader:
                loss = model(data)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss {loss}")
        
        
input_dim = 1000
output_dim = 1
hidden_dim = 100
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 2
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 10

# Perform train-test split
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create custom datasets and data loaders
train_dataset = UCFCrimeDataset(train_features, train_labels)
val_dataset = UCFCrimeDataset(test_features, test_labels)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define the data loaders
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True
    )
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False
    )
    
    temp1 = [i for i in range(0, 94003)]
    temp2 = [i for i in range(1, 94004)]

    edge_index = [temp1, temp2]

    edge_index = torch.Tensor(edge_index)
    edge_index = edge_index.to(torch.int)

    print("Shape of edge_index:", edge_index.shape)

    # Define the model
    feature_extractor = GCNFeatureExtractor(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim)
    head = EDLHead(input_dim, num_classes)
    model = MIL(feature_extractor, head, loss_fn)

    # Define the optimizer
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    # Train the model
    train(model, train_loader, val_loader, epochs)

    # Save the model
    model.save("model.pt")
```

after running the aboce code i'm facing below error:

```
Shape of edge_index: torch.Size([2, 94003])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 134
    131 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    133 # Train the model
--> 134 train(model, train_loader, val_loader, epochs)
    136 # Save the model
    137 model.save("model.pt")

Cell In[7], line 77, in train(model, train_loader, val_loader, epochs)
     75 model.train()
     76 for data in train_loader:
---> 77     loss = model(data)
     78     loss.backward()
     79     optimizer.step()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

TypeError: MIL.forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'edge_index'
```

Let me know what is the error or my code structure is only wrong? I have extracted frames from a video dataset(Anomaly and Normal) and then extracted features and labels from that frames and converted it into tensors
My features size and shape is Shape: torch.Size([94003, 1000])
Size: torch.Size([94003, 1000])
Length: 94003

and the labels Array Shape: (94003,)
Array Contents: [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]